# What is the correct definition of Selectivity : TPR or TNR? Since contradictory literature exists

Tags: terminology, sensitivity-specificity

The reason of my question is because contradictory articles exist. Talking about the confusion matrix's performance metrics, we can find:

- English wikipedia pages mention that `Selectivity = Specificity = true negative rate (TNR)` : https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Sensitivity_and_specificity
- French wikipedia page mentions that `Selectivity = Sensitivity = Recall = true positive rate (TPR)`  (in French : `Sélectivité = Sensibilité`) : [https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensibilité_et_spécificité](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensibilit%C3%A9_et_sp%C3%A9cificit%C3%A9)

Do you happen to use the notion of Selectivity, and how?

May that only be a disagreement between Anglo-Saxon and French conventions?

Would you suggest some academic reference about that?

Comment: You say "selectivity" a number of times, but it seems like you mean sensitivity, i.e. $P(T+|D+)$. If this is so, can you edit your title and your post? Selectivity could easily be confused; the first thing I thought of is selectivity in college admissions, i.e. something more like $P(Admitted|Test scores)$.

Comment: @WeiwenNg: That's the point of the question: does "selectivity" mean *sensitivity* or *specificity*? (Or something else, or nothing clearly defined.)

Comment: It looks like I am wrong. The link above is now working, and I see that selectivity is an actual term. I hadn't heard of it, which is why I thought it was used in error.